# Injecting my module in Dagger gives me NPE

Tags: android, dagger

Im trying to implement a simple example with Dagger where  Module returns just a string

**Module is :**

```
@Module(
    injects = { MainActivity.class }
)
 public class MyDataModule {

public MyDataModule() {
}

@Provides
public MyDataModule provideMyData() {
    return new MyDataModule();
}


public String createMyDataItems() {
    return "MyDataString";
}

}
```

**And Activity :**

```
@Inject MyDataModule myDataModule;

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_data);
    textView.setText(myDataModule.createMyDataItems());

}

}
```

And I get a NPE at the last line :

```
textView.setText(myDataModule.createMyDataItems());
```

Comment: where do u instance the myDataModule var?

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the object graph with

```
ObjectGraph.create(new MyDataModule())
```

You can read more in the [official tutorial](https://square.github.io/dagger/).

As a side note, I recommend you try setting up [Dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger/) instead of Dagger 1